# What is the best config file for kernel compilation

Tags: kernel, compiling

I need to recompile the kernel and I'm not sure what config file is the best

Should I use `make oldconfig` or `make defconfig`

I need all the features and modules that are installed by default in a Ubuntu Server kernel

Thank you

Comment: Have a read of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild - both mention using oldconfig, but I'm sure someone will be along soon to confirm (I don't have any experience of building kernels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just steal the config file for the Ubuntu version of the kernel you want to build. For example, say you wanted to compile kernel 4.0 yourself. Go to the [kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D), get and install the kernel. Then from your build location do:

```
cp /boot/config-4.0.0-040000-lowlatency .config
```

where in my example, I have used the lowlatency kernel, you might use a different version.
Now, and this is very important, the Ubuntu default configuration file has all debug information enabled. Such a kernel will take at least twice as long to compile and be huge. Before you compile do this:

```
scripts/config --disable DEBUG_INFO
```

I compile kernels several times per week and have never run any make config stuff.